# Is there a simple way to use only half of the images in underlying directories using Keras flow from directory?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

I am trying to work out how to use a subset of the images within directories in order to test if a larger dataset will actually help me classify some images (and for context, they are obscure images with seemingly random blobs (but they are not actually random) rather than shapes a human could distinguish by eye). I am using ImageDataGenerator with flow from directory in Keras, and so would like to test this on various different amounts of data.

This is the simple code I have so far too pull the data from the directories using generators.

```py
def load_the_data(batch_size):

    train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        rotation_range=50,
        validation_split=0.6,
        )

    train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_data_dir,
        target_size=(21, 21),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='categorical',
        subset='training'
        )

    validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_data_dir, # same directory as training data
        target_size=(21, 21),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='categorical',
        subset='validation'
        )

    return train_datagen, train_generator, validation_generator
```

Comment: What about `steps_per_epoch` when you call `fit_generator`? If you just want to test if number of images has anything to do with preformance then set `steps_per_epoch` to lower than `num_img/batch_size`  would work though.

Comment: Provided you explicitly use `shuffle=False` (maybe both in the generator and in fit), the comment above might work.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using `flow_from_dataframe` to take limited number of images to test by creating `dataframe` with all the images and labels from the directory and creating a subset of it.

You can follow the below code for the same.

Below is my sample directory structure with 10 classes in it.

[image]

**Creating a list of images and labels from the directory:**

```
import os
images = []
labels =[]
for sub_dir in os.listdir(train_data_dir):
  image_list=os.listdir(os.path.join(train_data_dir,sub_dir))  #list of all image names in the directory
  image_list = list(map(lambda x:os.path.join(sub_dir,x),image_list))
  images.extend(image_list)
  labels.extend([sub_dir]*len(image_list))
```

**Creating DataFrame and a subset of it.**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Images":images,"Labels":labels})      
df = df.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True) # To shuffle the data 
df = df.head(100) # to take the subset of data (I'm taking 100 from it)
```

**Creating ImageDataGenerator using flow_from_dataframe:**

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    rotation_range=50,
    validation_split=0.6,
    )

train_generator=train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
dataframe=df,
directory=train_data_dir,
x_col="Images",
y_col="Labels",
batch_size=32,
seed=42,
shuffle=True,
class_mode="categorical",
target_size=(21,21))
```

**Sample Output:**

> Found 100 validated image filenames belonging to 10 classes.

You can follow the same procedure for `validation_generator`

Comment: @Ryan If your issue is resolved using the above answer, please accept and upvote the answer, Thank you.

Comment: Your answer worked for me but I would suggest you fix the way you are showing your first part of the code.